# Nonlinear individual growth trajectories (quadratic and cubic trasformation of time) in linear mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, linear

I'm performing a Linear Mixed Models and I want to test if trajectories are nonlinear over time.

If I use only the linear term for time, the association was significant and I can explain the effect of time on my outcome.
When quadratic term was added the linear term lost the significance (but the quadratic terms remains significant), and I don't understand how to interpret this results.

Can someone suggest me how to understand better this aspect of linear mixed models and how to interpret this specific case?

---

[image: individual trajectories]

I have 33 subjects and 5 time points non equally spaced [range 4-8].
The model that best fit my data is the quadratic one.
Do tou need other info?

Thanks for the reply
Flavia

Comment: Can you give some more details of your specific case? Show us some plots? ...

Comment: I replide in answer section! Thanks a lot. Flavia